# Widgets occupying the whole screen

Tags: home-screen, app-widgets

I have a Samsung Galaxy Y phone, I use the Android App called as "Any.Do" to help me with my To-do list management.
One of it's widgets called as the "Any.Do Grande (4x4)" occupies the whole of my phone's homescreen.

Now, I know that the screen size of my mobile is relatively smaller than most android mobiles available in the Market.

So, my question here is: If a widget occupies the whole screen of my mobile, will it do so for mobiles of various different screen-sizes too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [android developers guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html)

> This grid can vary by device; for example, many handsets offer a 4x4 grid, and tablets can offer a larger, 8x7 grid

That being said, most phones have a 4x4 grid. One exception that I know of is the Galaxy Note which has a [5x5 grid](http://www.notebookcheck.net/typo3temp/pics/444ca179e7.jpg). Also I've read about custom ROMS or mods that change a [default 4x4 grid](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1802582) to 4x5 or 5x5